# regex match whole word only

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some issues with matching a whole world only in C#.

The string in particular is `C#BKN005` and I only want to search for the whole word. I'm using this regex:

```
\bC#BKN00([0-9]{1})\b
```

But if the string is `BKN005`, it returns true.

---

Here's the code I'm using:

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, @"\bC#BKN00([0-9]{1})\b", "ceiling $1 hundred broken.");
```

---

**Let me clarify. I have both `C#BKN` and `BKN` and I need to be able to distinguish between both of them.**

Comment: That regex will never match `BKN005`. Please post the code you're using to perform the match. There must be an error somewhere in that code.

Comment: Please post the code, as that string does not match.

Comment: what are you searching through? is regex the right way to go?

Comment: I updated my post to include the code.

Comment: `modify = modify.Replace("C#BKN005", "ceiling $1 hundred broken.");` makes more sense from what i can see

Comment: Please post the value of modify too.

Comment: *Sigh*, well, matching `a whole world` can be difficult at times.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I have both `#CBKN` and `BKN` and I need to distinguish between the two.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using a different prefix instead of C#.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't return 'true', if I run the following code:

```
public void Main()
{
    string matchstr = "\\bC#BKN00([0-9]{1})\\b";
    string modify = null;
    modify = Regex.Replace("C#BKN005", matchstr, "ceiling $1 hundred broken.");
    Console.WriteLine(modify);
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("BKN005", matchstr, "ceiling $1 hundred broken."));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get:

- ceiling $1 hundred broken
- BKN005

What would you like this to return?